# Why does the flex gap changes for some flex-items only?

Tags: css, flexbox

Input and Label:
[image: input + label]

Input, Icon and Label:
[image: Input + Icon + Label]

Icon and Label:
[image: Icon + Label]

Label only:

[image: Label]

There are no additional styles or margins applies to the input or label.

[image: Input CSS]

The container is flex with a gap set to 12px.

Where does that extra space come from when it's only the input and the label?

PS:
I am using Stencil.js.
The icon is a separate stand-alone component nested between the input and label, which are html elements. The icon is conditionally shown depending on whether or not an icon name is passed to the component.
This is what my code looks like:

```
 return (
       <a href="javascript:;" class={`dropdown-item ${this.checkboxColor}`}>
          {this.checkable && <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" class={`form-check-input`} />}
          <ifx-icon icon={this.icon}></ifx-icon>
          <label htmlFor="checkbox4" class="form-check-label"><slot /></label>
        </a>
    )
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible code example, the best we can do is guess what is going wrong. How exactly do you hide the icon? You need to use `display: none`, or remove the icon from the DOM. I could reproduce this behavior when using `visibility: hidden`. Also make sure there is no other element in the DOM.

Comment: I have updated my question. I can't show you a reproducible code because I am using Stencil.js, and this is a web component. The icon is also a separate web component.

Comment: The icon is always rendered, but when no name is given, it's "empty".

Comment: I just realized that if I remove the icon component, the gap is correct. Hm.. I wonder why?

Comment: Because any DOM element inside a flex container is considered as a flex item, even if it has no content or width.

Comment: if the icon is ALWAYS rendered it is a flex item so it has the gap

Comment: Yep, I fixed it. I was wondering if it would be better to use gap or use margins left and right for each respective element inside the container, but I went for the flex gap as it seemed easier. What are some of the disadvantageous of using gap rather than margin?

Comment: Gaps work also when wrapping flex items, which is very difficult with margins. In your case I think it doesn't really matter.